# QStringList is interpreted as an alias of QList<QString> in some contexts

Tags: qt, qt6, qstringlist

I've noticed that in two different build contexts, `QStringList` can be eihter interpreted as its own class, or as an alias to `QList<QString>`. The former is the expected behavior according to the documentation, while the latter is beyond my understanding.

I've developed a library that defines the following method:

```cpp
void findObject(const QString& objectType, int id, const QStringList& fields, std::function<void(QVariant)> callback);
```

(See: https://github.com/planed-es/QtOdoo/blob/da3419a721b1088223c472c82df9c325aafb1061/QOdoo.h#L137)

The library builds as expected, but when trying to create an executable that links to any of the functions or methods that use `QStringList` in its definition, I am being told that I'm using an undefined reference to:

```cpp
OdooService::findObject(QString const&, int, QList<QString> const&, std::function<void (QVariant)>)
```

Looking at the definition, it is not identical as the header's, which defines it as following:

```cpp
OdooService::findObject(QString const&, int, QStringList const&, std::function<void (QVariant)>)
```

I modified the library to replace all occurences of `QStringList` with `QList<QString>`, to try and remove the ambiguity. When I remove references to `QStringList` in any declarations that will be shared with other build targets, it builds and works as intented. I suppose this means that `QStringList` is interpreted in two different ways, depending on whether I'm building the library or my executable.

I've been able to reproduce the issue with a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <QOdoo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  OdooService service(QUrl("http://hello.com"));

  service.findObject("res.partner", 2, QStringList{}, [](QVariant) {});
  return 0;
}
```

This example fails to build if `findObject` is defined using `QStringList`. However, it builds properly if I rewrite its definition using `QList<QString>` instead. I'm pretty sure this is not supposed to happen. Anyone knows what might be up ?

Comment: I assume you have `#include <QStringList>` somewhere?

Comment: I think so, it should be included by QOdoo.h: https://github.com/planed-es/QtOdoo/blob/master/QOdoo.h#L5C5-L5C5
And QOdoo.h is included in the source file.

Comment: Are you building the library with Qt5 and your app with Qt6? I think `QStringList` used to be a separate class but then got reworked to be an alias to `QList<QString>` in Qt6

Comment: That was it, one target built with Qt5, the other with Qt6. My system prioritizes Qt5 over Qt6 when both are an option, apparently... I really was not expecting that.

Comment: @perivesta the Qt6.6 docs say "QStringList inherits from QList<QString>." It has been that way for a long time.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Looks like it. I might've gotten confused with the QVector/QList merge they did in Qt6.